# Kohana ORM and file upload issue... setting record logo to equal record logo when there is no image

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

This causes this error...

> Operand should contain 1 column(s) [ UPDATE `record` SET `logo` = ('',
>   '', '', 4, 0) WHERE `id` = '0' ]

```
if ($_FILES['logo']['name'] == '') {
    $record->logo = $record->logo;
}
else{
    // INSERTION WORKS FINE
}
```

I'm also using the Formo module if that makes a difference...

Is there a way to just kick-out the logo out of the insertion script altogether or such... since `$record->logo = $record->logo` causes a fail?

Answer (score 0):

```
$record->logo = $record->logo;
```

Would cause an error if $record->logo is not set..  You would have to atleast say:

```
$record->logo = '';
```

but the best thing to do would be to use `Validation::factory($_FILES)->check()`

```
if ( $logo->check() ) {
  // do your insert here
}
```

This is just a snippet from when i last managed this:

```
    $logo = Validation::factory($_FILES);
    $logo->rule('logo', 'Upload::not_empty')->rule('logo', 'Upload::type', array(':value', array('jpg', 'png', 'gif')));
    if ( $logo->check() ) {
      $logo = Upload::save($_FILES['logo'], NULL, 'assets/uploads/logo');
      $image = ORM::factory('image')->where('id', '=', $id)->where('type', '=', 'logo')->find();
      $path = explode('/', $logo);
      $path = end($path);
      $image->path = 'assets/uploads/logo/' . $path;
      $image->playlist_id = $id;
      $image->type = 'logo';
      $image->save();
    }
```